# Debugging devenv.exe memory dump in WinDbg

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, windbg

I'm trying to see what's causing my Visual Studio 2013 instance to hang all the time while I'm coding. I noticed that when it's hanging, it's using 1-3% CPU in Task Manager during the hang, so I dumped devenv.exe which is flagged as a 32-bit process (*32) in Task Manager. When I open it in the 32-bit version of WinDbg and run .effmach, I get:

```
0:000> .effmach
Effective machine: x64 (AMD64)
```

And when I try to load the CLR debugging extension I get:

```
0:000> .loadby sos clr
The call to LoadLibrary(C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\sos) failed, Win32 error 0n193
    "%1 is not a valid Win32 application."
Please check your debugger configuration and/or network access.
```

Just for grins I opened the dump with WinDbg 64-bit and tried the following:

```
0:000> .effmach
Effective machine: x64 (AMD64)
0:000> .loadby sos clr
0:000> !threads
SOS does not support the current target architecture.
```

It's like I'm caught between a rock and a hard place, unable to debug as 32-bit or 64-bit. My question is does anyone know which version of WinDbg, 32-bit or 64-bit I should use, and what extension(s) can be used to debug the devenv.exe process?

I also tried psscor4:

```
0:000> .load c:\debugging\extensions\psscor4\x86\psscor4.dll
0:000> !clrstack
SOS does not support the current target architecture.
```

WinDbg version is 6.3.9600.16384

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a 32 bit version of Task Manager in `\Windows\SysWOW64`. If you use that instead of the default, you'll get a proper 32 bit dump.